# proof $f(n) \in o(g(n))$ approach?

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics

In general, if I know a function $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ and I was able to show that $g(n) \notin O(f(n))$, does this imply that $f(n) \in o(g(n))$?

I'm referring to the big-O and small-o Landau notations
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

So if I know that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ i.e. there exists $c>0,$ and  there exists $M>0$ such that for all $n \geq M$: $f(n) \leq c g(n)$
And if I know that $g(n) \notin O(f(n))$ i.e. for every $c>0$, for every $M>0$: $g(n) > c f(n)$ for some $n \geq M$.

Can this imply that $f(n) \in o(g(n))$ i.e. for every $c>0$ there exists an $M>0$ such that for all $n \geq M: f(n) < c g(n)$?
I don't see this true.

Now, I've seen somewhere where they define $f(n) \in o(g(n))$ exactly as I mentioned except with $f(n) \leq  c g(n)$ instead of strictly. So can this general approach work then?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work in general, for instance let $g(n)=n$ and let $$f(n)=\begin{cases}n&n~~is~~even\\1&otherwise\end{cases}.$$ Then $f(n)=O(g(n))$ because $f(n)\leq g(n)$ for all $n$, and $g(n)$ is not $O(f(n))$ because for odd $n$ we have $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=\frac{n}{1}=n$ which is bigger than any constant. On the other hand $f(n)$ is not $o(g(n))$ because for even $n$ we have $f(n)=g(n)$ so we can't have $f(n)<cg(n)$ for arbitrary constants (e.g. $c=0.5$).

(It is irrelevant if you take $f(n)<cg(n)$ or $f(n)\leq cg(n)$. A simpler way to think of $f(n)=o(g(n))$ intuitively is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$. Sometimes it is defined this way.)

Comment: Makes sense. But I'm a bit confused now here, say we use the definition of limits. My claim now is if I know that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ and $g(n) \notin O(f(n))$, then $f(n) \in o(g(n))$ if I know the $\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ exists, is this true now?

Comment: My reasoning: Since $g(n) \notin O(f(n))$, then $f(n) \notin \Theta(g(n))$ hence $\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ can't be a nonzero constant. So the possibilities for $\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ is zero, $\infty$ or doesn't exist and if we assume the limit exists then it can't be $\infty$ else $f(n) \in \Theta(g(n))$. Hence it must be that $\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$ and thus $f(n) \in o(g(n))$. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @chris765 That makes sense. Just by $g(n)\notin O(f(n))$ there is no $C>0$ such that $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}<C$, which implies (if both sequences are positive) there is no $C>0$ such that $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}>C$, so the limit of $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$, if it exists, must be $0$. There is no guarantee that the limit exists though, for example in the above example the limit does not exist.